# How can I achieve noSmooth() with the P3D renderer?

Tags: opengl, processing, jogl

I'd like to render basic 3D shapes without any aliasing/smoothing with a PGraphics instance using the P3D renderer, but noSmooth() doesn't seem to work.

In OF I remember calling `setTextureMinMagFilter(GL_NEAREST,GL_NEAREST);` on a texture.

What would be the equivalent in Processing ?

I tried to use [PGL](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/opengl/PGL.html):

```
PGL.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER = PGL.NEAREST;
PGL.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER = PGL.NEAREST;
```

but I get a black image as the result.
If I comment `PGL.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER = PGL.NEAREST;`  I can see the render, but it's interpolated, not sharp.

Here'a basic test sketch with a few things I've tried:

```
PGraphics buffer;
PGraphicsOpenGL pgl;

void setup() {
  size(320, 240, P3D);
  noSmooth();
  //hint(DISABLE_TEXTURE_MIPMAPS);

  //((PGraphicsOpenGL)g).textureSampling(0);

  //PGL pgl = beginPGL();
  //PGL.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER = PGL.NEAREST;
  //PGL.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER = PGL.NEAREST;
  //endPGL();

  buffer=createGraphics(width/8, height/8, P3D);
  buffer.noSmooth();
  buffer.beginDraw();
  //buffer.hint(DISABLE_TEXTURE_MIPMAPS);
  //((PGraphicsOpenGL)buffer).textureSampling(0);
  PGL bpgl = buffer.beginPGL();
  //PGL.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER = PGL.NEAREST;//commenting this back in results in a blank buffer
  PGL.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER = PGL.NEAREST;
  buffer.endPGL();
  buffer.background(0);
  buffer.stroke(255);
  buffer.line(0, 0, buffer.width, buffer.height);
  buffer.endDraw();
}
void draw() {

  image(buffer, 0, 0, width, height);
}
```

(I've also [posted on the Processing Forum](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/21564/how-can-i-achieve-nosmooth-with-the-p3d-renderer#latest), but no luck so far)

Comment: If I remember correctly then `buffer.noSmooth()` does as intended. However calling `image()` fully ignores `noSmooth()`.

Comment: @Vallentin Thanks for the tip. My hunch is I probably need to get the reference to the PGL texture, bind it, then call something like ```pgl.getTexParameteriv(PGL.TEXTURE_2D,PGL.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER...``` on it, or something similar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were actually on the right track. You were just passing the wrong value to `textureSampling()`.

Since the documentation on [`PGraphicsOpenGL::textureSampling()`](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/opengl/PGraphicsOpenGL.html#textureSampling-int-)
is a bit scarce to say the least.
I decided to peak into it using a decompiler, which lead me to
[`Texture::usingMipmaps()`](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/opengl/Texture.html#usingMipmaps-boolean-int-).
There I was able to see the values and what they reflected (in the decompiled code).

```
2 = POINT
3 = LINEAR
4 = BILINEAR
5 = TRILINEAR
```

Where `PGraphicsOpenGL`'s default `textureSampling` is `5` (TRILINEAR).

*I also later found [this old comment on an issue](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/1272#issuecomment-18814727) equally confirming it.*

So to get point/nearest filtering you only need to call `noSmooth()` on the application itself, and call `textureSampling()` on your `PGraphics`.

```
size(320, 240, P3D);
noSmooth();

buffer = createGraphics(width/8, height/8, P3D);
((PGraphicsOpenGL) buffer).textureSampling(2);
```

So considering the above, and only including the code you used to draw the line and drawing `buffer` to the application. Then that gives the following desired result.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Also I noticed I was calling textureSampling after ```beginDraw()``` which had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to combine both GL_LINEAR and GL_NEAREST with one shader so the `((PGraphicsOpenGL) buffer).textureSampling(2);` was no option.

It was some digging, but this works for me:

```java
PGL pgl = beginPGL();
Texture ascii_map_tex = ((PGraphicsOpenGL)g).getTexture(ascii_map);
pgl.bindTexture(PGL.TEXTURE_2D, ascii_map_tex.glName);
pgl.texParameteri(PGL.TEXTURE_2D, PGL.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, PGL.NEAREST);
pgl.texParameteri(PGL.TEXTURE_2D, PGL.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, PGL.NEAREST);
pgl.bindTexture(PGL.TEXTURE_2D, 0);
endPGL();
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing (+1): that's a great tip!

Comment: O yeah, ascii_map is a PImage in this case.