# upscaling an image using Nearest-neighbor in processing

Tags: processing

While doing something like this in processing 3.5.4

```
void draw() {
  image(img.source, 0, 0, 50000, 50000);
}
```

The image comes out blurry.
Is there a way I can do this using nearest-neighbor?
The image is 1000 by 1000 pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's the default (`JAVA2D`) renderer you're using with `size()` then

simply calling [`noSmooth()`](https://processing.org/reference/noSmooth_.html) in `setup()` should do the trick.

If you use `P2D` you need to tell OpenGL to use nearest neighbour in `setup()`:

```
((PGraphicsOpenGL) g).textureSampling(2);
```

(I learned this from [Vallentin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43077189/how-can-i-achieve-nosmooth-with-the-p3d-renderer))